# loop only if filenames match in R

Tags: r, loops, arguments

In my directory I have files named as:

file1.a
file2.a
file3.a

file1.b
file2.b
file3.b

I want to graph the files according to their names (for instance: file1.a and file1.b; file2.a and file2.b ...etc). I am using a for loop in R as below:

```
     for (input1 in a_files){
     for (input2 in b_files){ 
    graph1<-read.table(input1, header=T, sep="\t")
    graph2<-read.table(input2, header=T, sep="\t")
    png(paste("header", input1, input2, ".png"))
    plot(graph1,graph2, type="l", col=c("darkred", "darkblue"), lwd=5)
    dev.off()
    }
    }
```

Although there is no problem with generating the plots, all the combinations of the graphs and filenames seem to be scrambled. This code generates graphs such as:

file1.a and file2.b
file1.a and file3.b ...etc

However, I would like to graph them only if the file names match (file1.a and file1.b ...etc).  What would be the argument function saying "if the file names match, then draw these graphs for every file in the folder"?

Comment: Not at all clear. What are we supposed to be thinking when you offer a plot function two dataframes as their x and y arguments? And when would 'file1.a' be a "match" to 'file1.b'?

Comment: Create a vector `ab_files` of file names without the extension. Then, with a single for loop try: `for (inputs in ab_files) { graph1<-read.table(paste0(inputs,".a"), header=T, sep="\t") graph2<-read.table(paste0(inputs,".b"), header=T, sep="\t") }` and so on.

Comment: To BondedDust: I would like to draw the histogram of 2 datasets together on the same x- and y-axes. The different datasets are denoted with *.a and *.b extensions. However, the filenames should match in order for me to properly compare them.  Therefore, I am looking for a code which states: "if the filenames without extensions match, draw the plot for these 2 files"... and I want to repeat this for all the files in the directory.  I hope I am clearer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
# File vectors
afiles <- c('file1.a', 'file2.a', 'file3.a')
bfiles <- c('file1.b', 'file2.b', 'file3.b')

# Combine so they match
combofiles <- data.frame(a = afiles, b = bfiles)

# plotting function
plotter <- function(f1) {

  graph1<-read.table(f1['a'], header=T, sep="\t")
  graph2<-read.table(f1['b'], header=T, sep="\t")

  png(paste("header", f1['a'], f1['b'], ".png"))
  plot(graph1,graph2, type="l", col=c("darkred", "darkblue"), lwd=5)
  dev.off()
}

# Apply to each row of combo
apply(combofiles, 1, plotter)
```

Comment: For some reason the code above plotted only the 1st dataset, therefore I tweaked the "plotter function" as: 'code'plotter <- function(f1) {
    graph1<-read.table(f1['a'], header=T, sep="\t")
    graph2<-read.table(f1['b'], header=T, sep="\t")
    png(paste("header", f1['a'], f1['b'], ".png"))
    plot(graph1, type="l", col=c("darkblue") , lwd=5)
    lines(graph2, col=c( "darkred"), lwd=5)
    dev.off()
  }
apply(combofiles, 1, plotter)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the code above plotted only the 1st dataset, therefore I found the solution by changing the "plotter function" as:

```
plotter <- function(f1) {
      graph1<-read.table(f1['a'], header=T, sep="\t")
      graph2<-read.table(f1['b'], header=T, sep="\t")
      png(paste("header", f1['a'], f1['b'], ".png"))
      plot(graph1, type="l", col=c("darkblue") , lwd=5)
      **lines(graph2, col=c( "darkred"), lwd=5)**
      dev.off()
      }

     apply(combofiles, 1, plotter)
```

Thanks everyone for the solution!